# how to connect php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have here a codes...it's not working... I don't think this is the right way to get data from php.

"How can i get that birthdate thing into the javascript code?"

```
<?php
include("../../connect.php");
    $yup=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE stud_id='2'");
    while($up=mysql_fetch_array($yup))
        {
            echo"$up[birthdate]";
        }

?>

<script>
    CountDownTimer('$up[birthdate]', 'countdown');
    function CountDownTimer( dt,id)
    {

        var end = new Date(dt);

        var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;
        var timer;

        function showRemaining() {
            var now = new Date();
            var distance = end - now;
            if (distance < 0) {

                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                return;
            }
            var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + 'days ';
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
        }

        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
    }

</script>
<div id='countdown'></div>
```

Comment: Obligatory Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Poor user3219866, all of his questions were downvoted and yet user3219866 only registered 2 days ago.

Comment: it's okay..!! I just want to learn more..what i have to do is to accept all comments that you have..it means that i have to study more,,, and yet..!I'm in highschool.

Comment: Its the begging that encourages downvotes not your genuine attempt to try.

Comment: okay no more begging next time... :)

Comment: @user3219866 - I was once in high school too and at the same time I self-taught myself several langauges.

Comment: @user3219866 - SO will be a great place for you to learn, if you post great questions with efforts shown.

Comment: don't you worry ... i will do better next time..!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number of birthdates coming from the database (it looks that way), you could build a PHP array from your database results, and output that as a JSON array.

In the PHP:

```
$result = array();
while($up=mysql_fetch_array($yup))
        {
           array_push($result, $yup);
        }
```

Then, in the appropriate location (like in the `<head>`):

```
<script>
dates = <? echo json_encode($result); ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To use variables from PHP in the rest of the document, you need to use the PHP tag.  So, 
**CountDownTimer('$up[birthdate]', 'countdown');** should be

```
CountDownTimer(<?php echo($up['birthdate']); ?>, 'countdown');
```

or, even better:

```
CountDownTimer(<?=$up['birthdate']?>, 'countdown');
```